# Excel: Counting the Dependents of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

How want to implement a function in Excel that can count the dependents for a given cell.

Example, suppose the following data:

```
|   | A | B | C |
| 1 |   |=A4|=A4|
| 2 |   |=A4|=A4|
| 3 |   |   |   |
| 4 |foo|=DEPENDENTCOUNT(A4)
```

In, cell `B4`, I want to show the number of time the cell `A4` was referenced. With this table, it should `4`, since `=A4` was used 4 times.

I have tried the following function, but it always returns 1:

```
Function DEPENDENTCOUNT(cell) As Integer
    DEPENDENTCOUNT = cell.Dependents.Count
End Function
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a spelling error in the *UDF()*:

```
Function DEPENDENTCOUNT(cell As Range) As Integer
    DEPENDENTCOUNT = cell.Dependents.Count
End Function
```

Secondly, that Property will work within a *Sub*, but not within a *UDF()*:

```
Sub qwert()
    MsgBox Range("A1").Dependents.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know the reason behind it not working in UDF?  Even putting in your `msgbox range("A1")...` doesn't work inside a UDF even if its not referencing anything outside the function.

Comment: Yes, typo. My actual code was OK, but the stackoverflow question had the typo.

Comment: do you know a workaround, to make it work inside a UDF?

Comment: @decasteljau ...........No........because the UDF does not "see" the other cells in the worksheet,it does not "see" the dependents.......